# Clarification on ε−δ proof of left-side limits

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

The question is the following: $\lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{1}{1-x} = \infty$

I have done some rough work and a proof(that is probably incorrect), but I am not exactly sure what a correct proof should look like for this particular type of limit.

Rough work:

$W.T.S.: \forall M > 0, \exists \delta > 0 \hspace{4pt} s.t. \hspace{4pt} 0 < 1- x < \delta \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x-1} > M$

$1-x < \frac{1}{M}$

$\delta \leq \frac{1}{M}$

$Proof. Given \hspace{4pt} M > 0, choose \hspace{4pt} \delta = \frac{1}{M}. Assume \hspace{4pt} 0 < 1 - x < \delta.$

then $1 - x < \delta$

We have proven $\frac{1}{1-x} > M$, as needed.

Q.E.D.

Comment: If $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, then wouldn't the limit be negative infinity?

Comment: Is the denominator $x-1$ or $1-x$?

Comment: @AlbertoTakase it is $1-x$. Very sorry, I typed it wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. There might be some typos in the Post, but with this information you are more likely to get an answer going into the details of the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-proof.

Comment: I only typsetted the actual question wrongly. On paper, I wrote the rough work and the proof using the correct question, and transferred all of that information into this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is how I would prove it. Use it as a comparison. Do not take it as the absolute only way to write the proof. In mathematics, we allow personalization in proofs. I am in the camp that frowns upon using logic notation outside a logic setting. If you adopt this philosophy, then you may find yourself getting a better response when showing your proof to others (especially professors and teaching assistants!).

**Proposition.** $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{1}{1-x}=+\infty$. That is to say, for each $M$ (positive integer; usually large), there exists $\delta>0$ such that for each real number $x$, if $1-\delta<x<1$, then $M<\frac{1}{1-x}$.

*Proof.* Fix an arbitrary $M$. Define $\delta:=\rule{30pt}{0.4pt}$. Fix real number $x$.
Assume $1-\delta<x<1$.
Observe
$$\begin{align}
0<1-x&<\delta,\\
\frac{1}{1-x}&>\frac{1}{\delta}>0.
\end{align}$$
Therefore if we choose $\delta:=\frac{1}{M}$, then we obtain $\frac{1}{1-x}>M$ as desired.
$\square$